# How to create the path to desktop for the target user..in C#.net

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, path, filesystems

I am developing image extraction application in .net using C# in VS2010.
i have created a path ,where the image will be extracted.But this path is specific to my system.

```
        string image1 = "c:\\Users\\Raghu\\Desktop\\r.bmp";
```

I want a path which should be general i.e when the project will be deployed ,the output file should be extracted in Target Users desktop.

how create a folder on desktop and and all my extracted files goes in it.
Any ideas! please help me!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Next code will return path to the desktop of current user:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
```

So, in your case it would be

```
string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
string image1 = System.IO.Path.Combine(desktop, "r.bmp");
```

Answer (score 1):

Environment.SpecialFolder (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) contains many definitions of system folder paths. Take a look which you need.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the `DesktopDirectory` for [`Environment.SpecialFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx). Something like this:

```
public static string GetDesktopDirectory()
{
    return Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
}
```

Then using the result of that method, you can use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) to append a file name to it.

```
var myFilePath = Path.Combine(GetDesktopDirectory(), "r.bmp");
```

`Path.Combine` is the general solution for this, as directly concating strings may result in double slashes, etc. This takes care of that for you.

Comment: And solution for only one backslashing? Thank you.